# How long it take for car engine to heat up to a normal range ? 2005 Toyota Camry 2.4L L4 FI DOHC 16V

Tags: camry, thermostat

I recently bought a used 2005 Camry with 157k miles on it. What I notice is that the thermostat gauge stays in the middle even while the car is running at 70mph. Today I noticed that it takes 3 minutes or around 1 mile for the gauge to come to middle. Is that normal? I was wondering if the engine/thermostate is working properly.

Comment: It will vary from a car to another and how you are pushing the car when it is still warming up but that seems very normal

Comment: @method - Outside temps will have a factor, too. If it's -30F out, it's going to take a lot longer for the vehicle to get up to temperature, especially if you are comparing it to an outside temp of 100F. At that temp, you're over half way there.

Comment: To OP: This sounds perfectly normal to me in most cases. It shouldn't take long for the engine to get to temp and as long as it is functioning correctly, you won't get above the 1/2 point on the gauge. Almost every OEM temp gauge I've seen is made to show the "normal" temp right about the middle of the gauge. I believe this is to make it easier for the driver to see when there's an issue.

Comment: Have you checked the user manual for your vehicle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 minutes seems to be OK during summer but may take much longer like 20-30 during winter to get to the stable operating temperature. So if it is during winter or even cold fall or spring it clearly seems to be too fast. If you remember the history how it was heating up when it was new or just bought or simply before  and it seems now to you it is too hot or heats up too much or fast suspect the worst i.e. the slow head gasket failure which will gradually increase till it heats to maximum even if the cooling fan later goes on (never do that while it can cause the engine damage). If the head gasket gets worn which separates the cooling liquid chambers inside the block from the cylinders and the combustion gases sealing the block with the head  the cooling fluid saturates with hot gases like a soda water with carbon dioxide which in feedback cases the the fluid to be hotter and of lower density which heats the engine more and more. You will see first that the level of coolant changes much more above the cold level on hot engine and may also be black dirty instead of normal pink, blue or green. Gasket also separates the coolant from oil so its damage will cause the water to be present in oil (and vice versa the oil in the coolant) and may cause the engine scratching and severe seizure damage. In any case if you notice some of those symptoms you must stop using the car immediately. In any case if you do not know cars engineering well and intuitively suspect something is wrong give the towed car to the mechanic for the check up and especially the cooling and oil systems.

Comment: I suspect Matt is not a real user - possibly a spammer copying and pasting text. The post does not answer the question at all. Matt - Once you post to Stack Exchange, the post is property of the community, so we are empowered and encouraged to improve it through edits. Or you could continue to get down votes.